# What is the significance of " Vratas" ( व्रत ) In Hinduism?

Tags: puranas, culture, dharma, tradition, ayurveda

What is the significance of **"Vratas  (व्रत )"** described in Hinduism. e.g. **"Haritalika (हरितालिका)" , "Rushi Panchami (ऋषि पंचमी)** etc.

Are there any scriptures pointing towards importance of "vratas" in Hinduism?

Comment: Matysa Purana describes many Vratas. See [this index](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/matsya-purana-2-volumes-IDJ548/). Check [Indian Scriptures - Matysa Purana](http://www.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/matsya-mahapurana/vol-i) for those chapters.

Comment: Related http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-is-the-reason-behind-fasting-vrat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vraat (Sanskrit : व्रत) means "vow, resolve, devotion", and refers to the practice of austerity, particularly in matters related to foods.

So simply  speaking , Vrata means to accept some rules of restrictive discipline.In **spiritual or Adhyatmik (आध्यात्मिक)** perspective Vrat means to apply control over our  physical sense organs,with a solemn vow to observe regulatory discipline.

**Significance of Varata in Hinduism -:**

Vrata is a resolution with a special purpose in mind. Devotees believe a great will power exists within such resolution. **Vrata and Vows adds power to the internal consciousness.**

The word  Vrata in spiritual or Adhyatmik sense also means to **move near to the supreme  God.**

Devotees refrain  or avoid themselves from food and water,on the day of Vrata to please the God.**The fasting aspect of Vrata or Upavas (उपवास) makes the mind strong and increases its firmness.**

Vrata bestows all kinds of advantage at the physical and spiritual levels. During the observance of vrat, devotee's completely abstains from food, or partly abstains from food and this gives **physiological rest to the digestive apparatus, which in turn awakens and increases the digestive power, leading to ease (comfort) of digestion and purification of the mind.**

The  fasting aspect of Vrata or Upavas (उपवास) **makes the mind strong and increases its firmness** and the stories connected with Vrat, if their purport is understood, can transform the life of a person.

**Devotees believes resolution is a means to awaken our dormant powers (सुप्त शक्ति).** Just as a person will employ all his powers to (successfully) attain any difficult objective, in the same way, to accomplish the objective of his resolution, he gathers all his powers and uses them.

One such vrata is known as **Ekadasi vrata**,  because it is performed ekadashi day . Each vrat has a mahatme (glories) (माहात्म्य) that describe the spiritual benefits of that particular fast.

So there are various physical as well as mental benefits of keeping the vratas. And in turn help devotees live happy ,healthy life and brings them closer to god. So Vratas have their significance in Hinduism.

[Varah Puran](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=SJyJfZqQw4EC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=In%20which%20purana%20importance%20of%20vrata%20is%20described&source=bl&ots=mPKs66Xmtx&sig=c5P_-nP7zgMWJFxh_y2JeKNhLc0&hl=en&sa=X#v=onepage&q=In%20which%20purana%20importance%20of%20vrata%20is%20described&f=false)And [Narad Puran](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=O5JZBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT30&lpg=PT30&dq=narad%20purana%20shlokas%20about%20vrata&source=bl&ots=1PZ_1UlpS3&sig=RM5RCaqUnsqn5oNoD14QUdXdTTM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh6PuY3prOAhXFOI8KHQwMB4sQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=narad%20purana%20shlokas%20about%20vrata&f=false) also describes some of the Vratas.

Note: the above  answer is compiled with taking help from these web sites [1](http://www.shreedarshan.com/hindu-vrat.htm) & [2](http://www.hinduism.co.za/vrat-.htm)

Answer (score 0):

> Vrat is fasting on a particular day in the worship of particular
> Diety. while the real meaning of Upwas is looking inward up means in
> vas means to stay. your are turning your senses inward to look for the
> atman inside to know who you are
>
> [source yahoo](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090426004853AAbXBCZ)

Comment: upa means nearby, next to. It is upa not up.

Comment: Yahoo is not an authentic source. Please cite any Purana or Hindu Scripture.

Answer (score 0):

I read the answers and surprised at perfect answers to Vrat. I like to pronounce aadyaatmika as Adhi aatmika that gives answer directly.
Purpose of Vrat:
To realise AATMAA of ourself - ADHI AATMIKA
Why ADHI? (More intense realisation?),
Answer: We live on Earth without a purpose. We all have commonality though humans are from differents parts of world with attachment to many faiths and attractions.
We never know the purpose for which we are on Earth. To realise it we need Vrat.

It is also possible to be born and to die without knowing purpose of life but such JANMA might have hurted lot of living beings /human beings on Earth by some deeds : actions, dependancies, feeding more than required, passion on sex, craze for spending and earning though born wealthy, jealous nature if born poor due to comparison between peers in schools/colleges/work, act of suppression to showcase talent if born neither rich nor poor etc. "Manu Smriti" says that dependency of a life on other lives in unavoidable but God in His Gita has said "One who realises Self as Embodied Brahman will attain God as a liberated soul from births & deaths".
Those who think souls dont exist can never understand the greatness of Vrat. Vrat starts in "Sankalpam and ends in Parsheshanam(acceptance of portion of saatvaa after offering to God)". It is very difficult to undertake Vrat. Vrat is an achievement for a human on Earth.