# Spiritual and Scientific rationale behind fasting

Tags: puranas

On ekadasi day Vaishnavites and saivites observe fasting. That too if it is vaikunta ekadasi vaishnanivites will be very strictly adhering. Is there any puranic evidence on fasting? Comparison of spiritual and scientific rationale needed.

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-is-the-reason-behind-fasting-vrat?rq=1

Comment: Where is the answer for scientific rationale?

Comment: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=leN5CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT253&lpg=PT253&dq=scientific+rationale+fasting&source=bl&ots=1SVihBBdnj&sig=19doN98JsPJ3nSam9Is6yo48UKo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij-bSFt-bOAhUKv48KHVliCPQQ6AEIRDAG#v=onepage&q=scientific%20rationale%20fasting&f=false

Comment: where are your own wordings on this? Copying and pasting everybody can do. You have to put forth your views after understanding the subject. I have asked the comparison but you are splitting and joining. Grow up from student level to the next level.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Scientific speculation or reasoning is off-topic for this site.

Comment: On Ekadasi day vaisnabas fast & on pradosha tithis Shiva devotees fast.This is to start with.Next coming to the scientific logic ,which seems ridiculous to me asking for(since science can't explain more than 90 % of nature's mystries).This is my take on fasting-Fasting is like the fire sacrifice(Homa/Yagna).In homa we use all external objects & the fire(Agni) to which oblations are poured and Agni carries them to the concerned deity.In fasts nothing external that is used, our belly fire(Jathar agni) acts like the carrier.

Comment: *The food we don't take gets  sacrificed to the concerned deity.Like if u are fasting on mondays its for Shiva etc on Tuesdays its for Gowri etc

Comment: @Rickross and Destroyer --I am having the answer in scientific angle also told by Maha Periava of Kanchi. In two days will post the answer.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Maha Periava was not a scientist .Then how valid a scientific argument his argument will be?:)

Comment: By fasting you are trying to control your senses. Usually, your senses say 'I want to eat', and you feed them. You are a slave to the senses. At least once a month, practice being their Master. This is the concept behind fasting. When I say you, I mean everyone. Good luck!

Comment: @Rickross-He is sarweswaran. You are a common man. I will paste link in two days. If you understand Tamil read or ask anybody to translate. read Deivathin Kural if you want to know more abour periava.

Comment: @Sai--This is general. I asked the comparison,