# Advantage of Sankasta hara chaturthi

Tags: belief, ganesha, food, vrata

I saw [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-is-the-reason-behind-fasting-vrat) , I want to know what's the 1) Advantage of **Sankasta hara chaturthi**

2) Why doing Tuesday is more helpfull.

3) Why we need to see moon and eat at night.

4)Why Rice are not allowed to eat on this day for those who are doing fasting....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performing this Vrata is more beneficial. We know that Lord Ganesha is the god of prosperity and dispeller of obstacles. Hence this vrata is recommended for overall prosperity and getting rid of obstacles in various areas of your life. By the grace of the lord one is blessed with health, wealth, and prosperity.

As the vrata ends in the evening, one has to do chandra darshana and do the concluding pooja before breaking the fast.

Tuesday is an auspicious day and "mangala" also means auspicious hence sankashta chaturthi of Tuesday is more potent and auspicious.

> [Sankashti Chaturthi](http://www.speakingtree.in/blog/how-to-do-sankashti-chaturthi-fasting) is observed on the **fourth day (Chaturthi)
>   of the waning phase (dark half of lunar month)** of the moon which is
>   also called as Krishna Paksha. The other name of this vrat is Sankata
>   Hara Chaturthi meaning the Chaturti that can alleviate all the
>   obstacles (Sankat means obstacles and Hara means the act of removal)
>   Incidentally, Ganesh is also called by another name ‘Vignesh’ or
>   ‘Vignaraj’ meaning the god who is the Lord of obstacles – the giver as
>   well as remover of obstacles according to the situation.
>
> The Sankashti Chaturthi falling on **Tuesdays is also called as
>   Angarika Sankashti Chaturthi** (Angarak is the Sanskrit term denoting
>   Mars – the Lord of Tuesday) which is the most **auspicious** of the
>   Sankashti Chaturthis. Based on the convenience of the person observing
>   this fast, total fasting or partial fasting can be taken up. The
>   period of this fasting stretches from the time of sunrise in the
>   morning on the dedicated day to the time of moonrise on the same
>   evening.
>
> In the morning of Sankashti Chaturthi, early rise is advised. The
>   observer takes holy bath and chants the names of Ganesh while bathing.
>   After this, the altar of Ganesh needs to be prepared and prayers must
>   be offered. People going ahead with their regular routine or official
>   works can do so after that excepting the fasting aspect. If they
>   remain home or take a day off, they can engage in scriptural study or
>   listening to divine stories or chanting the names of Lord Ganesh
>   throughout the day.
>
> In the evening, the fast is concluded after **sighting the moon and
>   offering pooja to Lord Ganesh.** The time of moon rise is mentioned in
>   the calendar. Those who have difficulties in witnessing the moonrise
>   may take note of this time and prepare for the conclusion of the vrat.
>   However, seeing the moon physically towards the end of the vrat is
>   said to be highly auspicious. After the time of moon rise, the
>   observer will set up the altar, install a picture or idol of Lord
>   Ganesh, offer a formal pooja and break the fast.

Comment: Moonrise is always around 9:30 pm on the Chaturthi, what if someone sleeps at 9pm and not able to break fast?

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain no it varies based on month and season see the examples here https://www.drikpanchang.com/vrats/sankashti-chaturthi-dates.html . one has to take his dinner after moonrise so i dont think many would sleep without taking dinner !

Comment: Thank you @RakeshJoshi, but if one sleeps, does the fasting fails?

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain not exactly but one can wake up.for a while and do Chandra darshana for a while pray to Lord and then sleep back. Cos Chandra darshana is an important part too

Comment: Thank you again @RakeshJoshi, are you aware about this as well https://www.quora.com/Ganesha-Why-should-you-not-look-at-the-moon-on-Ganesh-Chaturthi

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain yes there is a story about that so people avoid looking at moon but its okay if its seen also.. Should not fear

Comment: even I looked at this today, I am forwarding this to you since you are more knowledgeable on this matter, according to this page, there is specific timing during which moon should not be seen and I think it does not interfere with Fast breaking. Please see and confirm your understanding http://sankashti.com/moon-sighting-avoiding-timings-on-ganesh-chaturthi/2059/

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain you can follow it if you want. But i am.not much superstitious about it. Main is Ganesha worship. Simply staying hungry wont give you the results..one has to properly worship Ganesha and pray.

Comment: Thank you @RakeshJoshi, May God offer you all the befitting blessings

Comment: Thank you @RakeshJoshi, May God offer you all the befitting blessings

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain thanks and same to you too.

Comment: on further reading, I got to understand that moon seeing should be avoided only during shukla paksha "Bhadrapad Chaturthi", and it is Vinayak Chaturthi and not Sankashti Chaturthi, the ritual to observe moon while breaking fast is for Sankashti Chaturthi only, thus there is no contradiction.

Comment: Moon rise is in morning for Vinayak Chaturthi, and moon rise is in evening for Sankashti Chaturthi

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain that is okay but main focus should be Ganesha and not moon. Both Jainism and Hinduism venerates Ganesha